# Why the list icons dont appear?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using tinymce plugin and it works. But for example if the user click in the list button in the textarea the text is indented and the list icon appears in the textarea.

However then in the show.blade.php the text dont appear with the list icon. Do you know what can be the issue?

jQuery:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: 'image code link lists',
    relative_urls: false,
    file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
        // trigger file upload form
        if (type == 'image') $('#formUpload input').click();
    }
});
```

To show the text is used:

```
  {!! $post->description !!}
```

For example if in the textarea is introduced this content:

Example of a text in the textarea with a list:

- listem item1;
- list item 2;
- list item3;

In the db is inserted like:

```
<p>Example of a text in the textarea with a list:</p>
<ul>
<li>listem item1;</li>
<li>list item 2;</li>
<li>list item3;</li>
</ul>
```

In the show.blade.php appears like:

```
Example of a text in the textarea with a list:

listem item1;
list item 2;
list item3;
```

Comment: Can you inspect the element and check that the content is in fact missing? It might just be CSS overwriting the styles. Also, make sure that $post->description actually prints out something. Try printing $post with print_r($post); and make sure that description does in fact, have  a value. Other than this, it will be extremely hard to help you.

Comment: Thanks, inspecting the element there is the ul and the list items of the ul.

Comment: Can you check if there is any css that is effecting the list items

Comment: Im using bootstrap the <ul> has list style none. Do you know how to in the case of tinymce allow that the lists have the default list style?

Comment: This is a CSS issue, not php, not jQuery. You will need to either change the default styles for < ul > and < li > OR wrap the description in a < div class="something" > and add CSS rules like .something ul { list-style: disc, padding: 20px }.... etc... play with CSS and you will find your problem. Also, you can also turn off some CSS rules with the inspector and it will help you pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working, the "  {!! $post->description !!}" is inside a div with class ".description" but even the ".description{
  display: none;" dont works. And so this also dont works ".description ul{
  list-style: disc !important;
  padding: 20px !important;

}".
}
"